# Push notifications by username

Tags: push-notification, ionic2, token, theory

I have been looking for ways to send notifications to specific users and what I found was that I need the device token to do that.

I have tried Firebase and Ionic Cloud Service to do some pushs and it worked fine, but I'm wondering if it's possible to register a service with a key -> value, for exemple, register with the username and the token. If so, how can I do it?

And what is the best service to do it?

Thank you in advance for the help.

P.S.: I'm not asking for code, just the theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you question [`for example, register with the username and the token. If so, how can I do it?`] I understand following.

You mean to say, there is a mobile app, which user will sign up to use and you want to send the notification to registered user i.e. get send push notification by username.

To solve this, you can follow the steps mentioned below.

- On app launch when you get FCM registration token, save it to some intermediate location such as local storages along with device-id, mobile details etc..
- Create a backend API which can save username and registration token in DB.
- When a user signs up or signs in, then fetch the registration token from local storages, post username, token to backend API to save it. You can make backend API bit intelligent to handle multiple devices of the single user, distinguishable by device-id, mobile details.
- Then while sending API from the backend, you can fetch all registration ids of a single user and send the notification to that users using all tokens of that user in FCM API. Use registration ids as JSON array in "registration_id" field. FCM Document - [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-plain-text).

Comment: So, my API could contain a hash table with the device as key and user as value, in case the same user log in multiple devices, right? Also, for faster fetch, should have an array of users with their known devices (that they logged once) to prevent that 1 device as already another used logged.

Comment: yes, you can combine device-id and username as key - this is to prevent multiple users using 2 devices interchangeably.